# JQuery UI sortable not working for more complex list item contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm having a confusing time getting sortable to behave properly:

this works as I'd expect:

```
<ul class="unstyled" id="resource-list">
 <li>a</li>
 <li>b</li>
 <li>c</li>
</ul>


$("#resource-list").sortable()
$("#resource-list").disableSelection()
```

but this doesn't

```
<ul class="unstyled" id="resource-list">
 <li>
 <div class="span3">
  <button class="btn btn-link"><i class="icon-remove"></i></button>
 </div>
 <div class="span9">
      <img class="img-polaroid" src="https:s3.etc.grover-00001.png">
     </div>
 </li>
 <li>
 <div class="span3">
  <button class="btn btn-link"><i class="icon-remove"></i></button>
 </div>
 <div class="span9">
      <img class="img-polaroid" src="https:s3.etc.grover-00002.png"></div>
 </li>
 <li>
 <div class="span3">
  <button class="btn btn-link"> <i class="icon-remove"></i></button>
 </div>
 <div class="span9">
       <img class="img-polaroid" src="https:s3.etc.grover-00003.png">
     </div>
 </li>
</ul>

$("#resource-list").sortable()
$("#resource-list").disableSelection()
```

In the second case, the `<li>s` render properly, and seem to more or less drag as expected, but when released, the list returns to its original ordering. the sort, create, and stop events are firing, but update does not.

Now I tried it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/R8fFK/) and it sorts properly.

I'm using bootstrap and meteor here, if that seems relevant.

Comment: Hmm, everything works: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rusln/t6gZQ/), not sure what the problem is  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that the sortable interaction use the position in pixels, the width and the height of the list items to know whenever the mouse is over the element inside the list or not, and so, decide the position where is gonna be droped the item that is been dragged. I guess that if you place the `<div>`'s inside the `<li>`'s , withouth annything besides that inside, then it makes a mess and the `<li>`'s don't have a propper height and so the jQuery UI is unable to know if you are inside the `<ul>` and in which position between the list items is pointing the mouse.

I've found that you can fix it (at least for chorme)  if you set a fix height in the `<li>` 's or you just place a `&nbsp;` just inside the `<li>` but outside the `<div>`'s . Personally i like more the first solution but i think that ,in your situation, it will be more useful the second one:

```
<ul class="unstyled" id="resource-list">
    <li>&nbsp;
        <div class="span3">
            <button class="btn btn-link"><i class="icon-remove"></i></button>
        </div>
        <div class="span9">
            <img class="img-polaroid" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/lipwriting/grover-00001.png">
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>&nbsp;
        <div class="span3">
            <button class="btn btn-link"><i class="icon-remove"></i></button>
        </div>
        <div class="span9">
            <img class="img-polaroid" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/lipwriting/grover-00002.png">
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>&nbsp;
        <div class="span3">
            <button class="btn btn-link"> <i class="icon-remove"></i></button>
        </div>
        <div class="span9">
            <img class="img-polaroid" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/lipwriting/grover-00003.png">
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
<script language="Javascript">
$("#resource-list").sortable()
$("#resource-list").disableSelection()
</script>
```

Comment: That works. Hmm. I do wonder if there's a less hacky way to do it, but that'll do for the nonce!